# Virtual function is not getting overridden

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I can't figure out why my virtual function is not being overridden, when looking up examples online I can't spot what I'm doing wrong, I must be missing something.

Base Class

```
class HashTable {
// removed some unrelated functions and data to keep this page short

void Insert(int key, HashTable *htable)
    {
        int pos = Find(key, htable);
        if (htable->table[pos].info != Legitimate)
        {
            htable->table[pos].info = Legitimate;

            int rKey = Reverse(key);

            htable->table[pos].element = rKey;
        }
    }

virtual int Find(int key, HashTable *htable)
    {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Children Class

```
class SingleHash : public HashTable {

     int Find(int key, HashTable *htable)
    {
        int hashVal = HashFunc1(key, htable->size);

        while (htable->table[hashVal].info != Empty &&
            htable->table[hashVal].element != key)
        {
            hashVal = hashVal;
            hashVal = hashVal % htable->size;

            prob = prob + 1;
        }

        trackProbes(prob);
        return hashVal;

    }
};

class DoubleHash : public HashTable {

     int Find(int key, HashTable *htable)
    {
        int hashVal = HashFunc1(key, htable->size);
        int stepSize = HashFunc2(key, htable->size);

        while (htable->table[hashVal].info != Empty &&
            htable->table[hashVal].element != key)
        {
            hashVal = hashVal + stepSize;
            hashVal = hashVal % htable->size;

            prob = prob + 1;
        }

        trackProbes(prob);
        return hashVal;

    }
};
```

What my main is looking like

```
int main()
{
int value, size, pos, i = 1;
    int choice = 1;

    HashTable *htable = new SingleHash;

    cin >> value;

    htable->Insert(value, htable);

    // more unrelated stuff   
}
```

When I run my program it just returns what's in the base class (0) when I make a call to Insert.

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you're missing virtual declaration in your DoubleHash::Find

Comment: Seems fine. How do you know the function of derived class wasn't called? Did you debug it?

Comment: @wizurd, while adding `virtual` is considered good programming practice by some, it is strictly not necessary for correctness.

Comment: add override keyword in dervied classes and then check error log, if your compiler accept c++11

Comment: and more -  htable->size is it function or class member?

Comment: @songyuanyao when i run it, it finds only whats in slot zero. I ran some test to print some data if one of the child class where called and nothing printed out.

Comment: @jonezq its a class member. Singlehash and doublehash are friend classes to hashtable. Ill try override keyword next.

Answer (score 1):

There are compile errors in code you provided like functions your not declared public for basics.

I tried to make MCVE for you, and it seems to be working fine.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class HashTable {
public:
    void Insert(int x)   {
      Find(x);
    }
    virtual int Find(int x)    {
        cout<<"base hash find \n";
        return x;    }
};

class SingleHash : public HashTable {
public:
     int Find(int x)    {
        cout<<"single hash find \n";      
        return x*2;
    }
};

class DoubleHash : public HashTable {
public:
     int Find(int x)    {
        cout<<"DOuble hash find \n";      
        return x*3;    }
};
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int value;
    HashTable *hsingle = new SingleHash;
    cin >> value;
    hsingle->Insert(value);
    HashTable *hdouble = new DoubleHash;
    hdouble->Insert(value);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is :

> single hash find
>
> DOuble hash find

Comment: This isn't really an answer. It would be better suited as a comment indicating inability to reproduce, possibly with a link to that code on an online compiler.